# How to start working on previous commit on GitHub

Tags: android-studio, github

I am developing an android application. While depending it crashed. Each step I made a commit to GitHub. So I want to get the commit of the last successful build of my project to the current project. How can I do that?

Comment: You want to revert to last commit?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git commit -m "reset to last working commit"
```